# Any way to boot repair without original installation drive

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, grub, ubuntu-14.04, bootrepair

Some time ago I installed **Ubuntu** (14th version) on my laptop along with Windows 8.1 using a bootable CD drive. But now I wanted to remove Ubuntu and so I deleted the partitions that I created for Ubuntu. Now I have to repair Windows boot but I do not have that CD drive from which I installed Ubuntu. Is there any way to repair the boot without original installation drive? Can I create another bootable drive and repair Windows boot from that.

P.S. - The Ubuntu installation process didn't go well. After I installed it alongside windows, whenever I used to start the laptop, I would get a **grub** screen and I have to type **exit** in order to go to the screen where it shows the OS choices. There were sometimes mounting problems in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have Windows installation DVD available,
you can download it from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/home

After creating media using the tool downloaded from above, boot from DVD or USB and follow the instructions found here:

http://www.techspot.com/guides/630-windows-8-boot-fix/

Here's quick summary:

- Select Repair your computer in the bottom left corner.
- Select Troubleshoot
- Select Advanced
- Select Automatic Repair and try to boot normally without DVD/USB
  connected.

If Automatic Repair didn't help:

- Go to same place as before but select Command Prompt
- And use the following command: `bootrec /fixmbr`
- Boot without DVD/USB

Answer (score 0):

This Ask Ubuntu question describes a similar situation and has an accepted answer that may solve the problem - [How to load Windows 7 from GRUB rescue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316341/how-to-load-windows-7-from-grub-rescue#316385).  Basically it uses the Ultimate Boot CD to enable running the boot recovery commands.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a Windows installation DVD or repair CD, you can boot to a repair command prompt (shift + f10 at the first screen) and run:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

If not, you can always create a bootable windows USB and install a bootloader like GRUB from there.

Comment: OP asked a solution without using the 'original installation drive'.